# Given a sequence of independent random variable $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ with $f_X$, how to find $f_A$ if $A = S_n/n$ is their average

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

My book gives the following. For a standard normal distribution:
$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$$
The density of the sum of n independent standard normal random variable ($S_n$) is:
$$f_{S_n}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}e^{-x^2/2n}$$
Similarly for the exponential distribution
$$f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$$
The density of the sum of n independent random variable each with the same exponential density is:
$$ f_{S_n}(x)=\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda x}(\lambda x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$
Where $S_n = X_1 + X_2 +...X_n$. If $A = S_n/n$ and I want to find $f_A$ for the standard normal and exponential density $f_X(x)= e^{-x}$, is the following approach correct:
$$F_A(a) = P(S_n/n < a) = F_{S_n}(na)$$
$$dF_A(a)/da = f_A(a) = nf_{S_n}(na)$$

From this, $f_A$ for the standard normal case:
$$f_{A}(a)=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-na^2/2}$$

$f_A$ for the exponential case:
$$ f_{A}(a)=\frac{n^ne^{-na}x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$

This doesn't match the solution in my book below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is wrong.

Normal distribution.  For large $n$ the distribution should approach a $\delta$ function, which yours does.  The book spreads out to be flat.

Exponential distribution.  You have a minor error, using $x$ when you mean $a$.  For $n=1$, your answer is correct, while the book has an extra factor of $x$.